# JDeveloper + ADF + maven configuration

Tags: maven, configuration, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm trying to implement ADF + maven in JDeveloper 12c and I haven't found many tutorials with these two together.. however one that I saw said to create a Maven Application but that option doesn't show... (when I do New -> Application (-> Maven) )

*I'm talking about this tutorial http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/maven11g-090173.html#5*

Any thoughts?
Also, do you think I should start by creating a ADF Fusion Web Application, instead of a Maven project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i would suggest you to take a look at this video: [Introducing Maven Support in JDeveloper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ht8JgEAmrI8). At the beginning of the "practical" part it shows how to load the Maven extension into JDev, and this should probably be the reason why you don't have the `Maven Application` option into the creation wizard. Anyway, by loading the extension, you will be able to create a Fusion App and use Maven to build it

Comment: I have youtube blocked here (company) but I'll be sure to check it at home, thank you!
(if it works, i'll then accept your awnser*)